# HCMWorker field values not visible in campaign target

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have created a new table `TableA` which contains several fields:

```
ContactID
Category
Comment
HCMWorkerRecId
```

Now I am creating a new Campaign, and want to add a new Target, I can choose the values from `ContactID` and `Category` but the HCMWorkerRecId field is not showing any values to choose from. When i use this table as a `DataSource` in a form, it is not a problem to choose the `PersonnelNumber` of the worker. I am using a `Field Group` to resolve the `PersonnelNumber` of the stored `RecId`.

Any suggestions why the value of the `HCMWorker` can not be selected in the Campaign target Query? I have compared the field with the other fields, but i can't find any noticable differences.

Comment: Your field `HCMWorkerRecId` extends of `HcmWorkerRecId` *EDT*? if you open your table can you choose any value for this field?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, yes, the field extends of HcmWorkerRecId, and from the table i can choose workers without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

RecIds are not supposed to be visible/selected in UI by the users, what you probably want to do is use a reference group instead, please refer to this: [How to use reference groups](http://gautamax.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/howto-use-reference-group-in-form_19.html)

Comment: I am using a reference group for it, the point is i can't use the worker in a campaign target query.